# i have lots of if else condition how to reduce them

Tags: objective-c

I have a text field and used numberOfRowsInSection for creating more than 50 text fields. After that I use the if else condition, but it was time consuming and a lengthy method so I want to reduce my if else condition. I don't want to use the switch condition. What should I do?

```
if (textField.tag == 0)//cust add line 1
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 1)//cust add line 2
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}

else if (textField.tag == 2)//kyc line 1
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 50)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 3)// kyc line 2
{

    [self.view endEditing : YES];

    DatePickerViewController *dateViewContrl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier : @"DatePickerViewController"];

    dateViewContrl.delegate = self;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        //dateViewContrl.preferredContentSize=CGSizeMake(325, 200);
        dateViewContrl.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(290, 200);
    }

    popcontrol = [[WYPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:dateViewContrl];
    [popcontrol.delegate self];

    //        _currentfield=_dateTextField;
    NSLog(@"%f   %f",popcontrol.popoverContentSize.height,popcontrol.popoverContentSize.height);
        CGRect rect_ = [self.view convertRect : textField.frame fromView : textField.superview];
    [popcontrol presentPopoverFromRect : rect_
        inView : self.view
        permittedArrowDirections : WYPopoverArrowDirectionAny
        animated : YES
        options : WYPopoverAnimationOptionScale];

    return NO;
}
else if (textField.tag == 4)
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self DropDownGendview : textField];
    return NO;
}
else if (textField.tag == 5)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 250)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 6)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 310)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 7)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 370)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 8 || textField.tag == 13 || textField.tag == 20)
{
    [self.view endEditing : YES];
    [self DropDownview : textField];
    return NO;
}
else if (textField.tag == 9)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 510)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 10)//cor email
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 630)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 11)//desig
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 700)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 12)//level
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 770)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 14)//level
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 910)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 15)//level
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 980)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 16)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 1050)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 17)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 1140)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 18)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 1240)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 19)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 1310)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 21)
{
    NSLog(@"state dropdown %ld",(long)textField.tag);
}
else if (textField.tag == 22)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 1520)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 23)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 1590)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 24)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 1660)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 25)
{
    [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset : CGPointMake(0, 1730)];
}
else if (textField.tag == 26)
{
    [self.view endEditing : YES];
    [self dropDownPurposeView : textField];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: There clearly as too much magic numbers. But, for instance, for tag 10,11 and 12, the y of the point, is 630+((tag-10)*70), and there are other similarities too. But I think that you issue lies more in the way to think about that rather than you if/else optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent a lot of these **if** statements with data, using a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int tag;
    int pointX;
    int pointY;
} Values;

const Values values[] = {
    {0, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 0},
    {2, 0, 50},
    // etc
};
```

then iterate through **values** and determine if your tag is in it:

```
int i;
bool found = false;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]); i++)
{
    if (values[i].tag == textField.tag)
    {
        [_customerFormTableView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(values[i].pointX,
                                                              values[i].pointY)];
        found = true;
        break;
    }
 }

 if (! found)
 {
      // do more complicated operations here
 }
```

you can speed up the **for** statement with a binary search, if the tags are sorted.

Comment: What is const Values values[] mean by this

Comment: It means the data within the values[] array is unchangeable -- it's constant

Answer (score 0):

You can try with switch case statement.It is better one instead of having lots of if else condition.If you use swit case it will improve your performance rather than having multiple if else condition.

A switch statement allows a variable to be tested for equality against a list of values. Each value is called a case, and the variable being switched on is checked for each switch

```
        switch(expression){
               case constant-expression  :
                   statement(s);
                   break; /* optional */
               case constant-expression  :
                    statement(s);
                    break; /* optional */

             /* you can have any number of case statements */
                default : /* Optional */
                statement(s);
           }
```

Generally  the expression used in a switch statement must have an integral or enumerated type or be of a class type in which the class has a single conversion function to an integral or enumerated type.

For more   details go with this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/switch_statement_in_objective_c.htm

Comment: But in this I have to check every text field tag and I don't want this.i already mentioned above

Comment: @VijendraYadav No you don't, implement a `case` for each tag you want to check and for the other tags the `default` statements whill be executed. The `default` statements can be nothing. In your code is no `case 13`.

Comment: I understand how to use switch but I want new logic to reduce such a lengthy code.I know switch is faster than if else but when I use switch I have to check every tag with case so I expect anything new

Comment: Yadav there is no other way to use any new one instead of switch case.You should use switch case.That will be good for you.You have very length if else condition.When running application that is not good for you.So use switch case.